# Reference that the blow-up of a smooth variety along a smooth subvariety is smooth.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, blowup

Accoding to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21232/when-is-a-blow-up-non-singular):

> The blow-up of a non-singular variety along a non-singular subvariety is well-known to be non-singular

Is that difficult, or rather trivial? In the latter case, what is a hint to solve it? If its difficult, what is a reference? I scanned Hartshorne, Chapter II 7, where the general blow-up is defined, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: See Theorem 22.3.10 in Vakil, *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*.

Comment: Here is an informal idea: if you blow-up along $Z \subset X$, then you just need to look around the preimage of $Z$ since the preimage of $X - Z$ is isomorphic to $X-Z$. To do this you can take an infinitesimal neighbourhood of some $z \in Z$ when you should be able (?) to reduce to the base of $L \subset \Bbb A^n$ where $L$ is a linear subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **Theorem II 8.24** in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*.