# Blowing up a smooth variety at a smooth variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[This previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359766/reference-that-the-blow-up-of-a-smooth-variety-along-a-smooth-subvariety-is-smoo) asks if it is trivial to prove that the blow-up of a smooth variety at a smooth variety is smooth. A reference to Hartshorne Theorem II 8.24 is given.

My question: Is there an intuitive argument for this? Is there a simple argument for this fact if we restrict to, say, the blow-up of an algebraic set of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: The short answer is that sufficiently locally, a smooth subvariety of a smooth variety looks like $\Bbb A^m\subset \Bbb A^n$, and the blowup of that is smooth. Would this be the sort of answer you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's due to the local nature of the blow-up.